# Discord.js - Trying to both await an async process and allow recursive calls of a wrapper

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await, discord.js

This one has a ton of moving parts that I've tried to simplify down as much as possible, and I still learning about async/await processing, so bear with me -

So I'm trying to write chat commands for a Discord chatbot with discord.js. The command that I'm having trouble with, triggered by a message beginning in `!aut`, is supposed to take in a string of user input (that follows the command itself) and return another string; if the user does not provide a string, I want it to grab the content of the message immediately above the message containing the command (i.e. 2nd most recent) and use that as the input string.

However, testing this latter case, it keeps throwing this error:
`(node:17896) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message`

I've structured the bot with an event listener that listens for commands and calls the wrapper function `execute(string, channel)` if it detects one; the wrapper then calls the appropriate utility function for that command to get a string that in then passes back to the listener, which then sends the string out to the channel.

The utility function `com_aut(array)` is working perfectly fine; the problem is that the default empty string `sComResult` defined within the wrapper is being returned to the listener before it can be overwritten by `com_aut`:

```
client.on('message', pMessage => {
    if (executable(pMessage.content) == true) {
        let sResult = execute(pMessage.content, pMessage.channel);
        pMessage.channel.send(sResult);
    }
});

function execute(sMessage, pChannel = null) {

    // strip off the initial ! that marks the message as a command; whatever comes immediately afterwards is the command
    let args = sMessage.substring(1).trim().split(/ +/g);
    let cmd = args[0];
    // don't include the command itself among the rest of the arguments passed to it
    args = args.splice(1);

    let sComResult = "";
    switch(cmd){

        ...

        case "aut":
            if (args.length < 1) {
                // input string that should be in args actually isn't, so grab the content of the 2nd most recent message instead
                pChannel.fetchMessages({ limit: 2 }).then(pMessages => {
                    sComResult = com_aut([pMessages.last().content]);
                });
            } else {
                // input string is present in args, so just use that
                sComResult = com_aut(args);
            }
            break;
    }
    return sComResult;
}
```

`TextChannel.fetchMessages` is asynchronous - or returns a Promise, at least - so I tried making the wrapper asynchronous as well so I could force it to `await`. Plus the necessary changes in the listener, I found that this worked:

```
client.on('message', pMessage => {
    if (executable(pMessage.content) == true) {
        execute(pMessage.content, pMessage.channel).then(sResult => { pMessage.channel.send(sResult) });
    }
});

async function execute(sMessage, pChannel = null) {

    // strip off the initial ! that marks the message as a command; whatever comes immediately afterwards is the command
    let args = sMessage.substring(1).trim().split(/ +/g);
    let cmd = args[0];
    // don't include the command itself among the rest of the arguments passed to it
    args = args.splice(1);

    let sComResult = "";
    switch(cmd){

        ...

        case "aut":
            if (args.length < 1) {
                // input string that should be in args actually isn't, so grab the content of the 2nd most recent message instead
                pMessages = await pChannel.fetchMessages({ limit: 2 });
                sComResult = com_aut([pMessages.last().content]);
                });
            } else {
                // input string is present in args, so just use that
                sComResult = com_aut(args);
            }
            break;
    }
    return sComResult;
}
```

However, NOW the problem is that I can't call `execute(string, channel)` recursively, which I do when piping the output of one string-output command into another, string-input command. (Which is also why the wrapper exists in the first place instead of the listener just being linked directly to the utility functions) This involves an `execute` call within `execute` itself. I'll just [link to pastebin](https://pastebin.com/L5yXJ0L8) at this point, but it's throwing a type error since it's not able to get a value back from the nested `execute` and so it ends up trying to call `null.then`:

```
(node:6796) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: pInnerPromise.then is not a function
```

How can I structure my code so that it properly awaits the fetchMessages query before moving on, but still allowing recursive calling of the wrapper function (or some other way to pipe)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code

```
    if (executable(sInnerCom) == true) {
   // here you are using await so promise is already resolved.     
    let pInnerPromise = await execute(sInnerCom, pChannel);
   // no need to use then, you can return result direct
        pInnerPromise.then(result => { sInnerComResult = result });
    }
```

It should be like this

```
   if (executable(sInnerCom) == true) {
        let result = await execute(sInnerCom, pChannel);
         sInnerComResult = result ; 
    }
```

or like this

```
if (executable(sInnerCom) == true) {
        sInnerComResult = await execute(sInnerCom, pChannel); 
    }
```